# ASP.NET MasterPage Postback not working from homepage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, postback

I have this textbox and submit button in a `MasterPage`

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Height="23px" Width="150px"></telerik:RadTextBox>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="searchType" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" Width="160px">
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">Authors</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2">Quotes</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And here is the code in `MasterPage` which executes when a user clicks the search button

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (searchType.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/quotes/authors/search/" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtsearch.Text)+"/1");
    } 
    else 
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/quotes/search/"+ HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtsearch.Text)+"/1");
    }
}
```

It works from any page, except from the home page. If you access the homepage with /Default.aspx it works.

this is the site http://www.quotestemple.com

Comment: Can you please also place here the master page place holders, the input code.

Comment: I would disagree with your last statement... it doesn't work for me even with "default.aspx" in the root of the domain

Comment: Can you please post your btnSearch html too.

Comment: the btnsearch code is not relevant, because the postback does not execute the masterpage redirect. So it does not reach there.

Comment: Aristos@ what input code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your website and attempting to regenerate what's happening there using your posted code above, it seems you haven't put an OnClick event on the search button. So when the button is clicked, it's only doing a postback without going through the code so there's no event to fire.

Try adding **OnClick="btnSearch_Click"** to the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"/>
```